# SQL Query that Returns the Sum of Field depending on ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

In the top picture is what I have in the SQL Table.

I have this Query that gives me the result in the bottom gridview. The query will return in The TransTypeDesc Column the largest EstimatedTransTime. As you can see Car is the largest EstTransTime in Q1.

The only thing that I dont have is the TotalEstimatedTransTime based on the DisplayNum. So for Q1 I should have 31 min.

```
  SELECT t1.DisplayNum, t1.TransTypeDesc, t1.SubQueueId, t1.EstimatedTransTime 
  FROM vwQueueData AS t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vwQueueData AS t2 ON t1.DisplayNum = t2.DisplayNum AND t1.EstimatedTransTime < t2.EstimatedTransTime 
  WHERE (t2.DisplayNum IS NULL) AND (t1.Called IS NULL) AND (t1.SubQ = @SubQ)
```

[image]

HERE IS THE SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8983/1

Comment: How do you expect to pick `TransTypeDesc` among several possibilities?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight TransTypeDesc will be the highest EstimatedTransTime

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the TrasTypeDesc is already working I just need to sum all the EstimatedTransTime for Q1 for example.

Comment: It's going to be hard to SUM() the EstimatedTransTime column as it is of type `varchar`.  You would need to ensure that it is an actual numeric column or sum wont work the way you want.

Comment: @Evanlewis its an int. Ignore the min

Comment: @Evanlewis http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8983/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something as per below:

```
SELECT t1.DisplayNum, t1.TransTypeDesc, t1.SubQueueId, SUM(t1.EstimatedTransTime) 
FROM vwQueueData AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vwQueueData AS t2 
     ON t1.DisplayNum = t2.DisplayNum AND 
        t1.EstimatedTransTime < t2.EstimatedTransTime 
WHERE (t2.DisplayNum IS NULL) AND 
      (t1.Called IS NULL) AND (t1.SubQ = @SubQ)
GROUP BY t1.DisplayNum, t1.TransTypeDesc, t1.SubQueueId
```

Basically, add the SUM function to the 'EstimatedTransTime' column.
Then perform a group by on the DisplayNum column in order to get the desired output.

Comment: This stills does not add, but I can think we are going towards the right direction.

Comment: Try the below. I used it using your link. A few columns and joins are missing to make the example more simpler. Basically the below query gives you what you need:                                         SELECT t1.DisplayNum, SUM(t1.EstimatedTransTime) 
FROM tblTest AS t1 
GROUP BY t1.DisplayNum

Comment: With that query it doesnt display the largest TransTypeDesc. I need to have the SUM and the largest TransTypeDesc